# Escaping brackets in bash scripts

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that's trying to set an environment variable by writing to .bash_profile. The value of the environment variable has a `(`. Here's the script:

```
echo "export ABC=Abcd123456%(" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

But I keep getting this error even though I'm escaping the `(` with `\(`:

```
/root/.bash_profile: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/root/.bash_profile: line 14: `export ABC=Abcd123456%\('
```

I tried escaping the `(` with `\(` by using `echo "export ABC=Abcd123456%(" >> ~/.bash_profile` since `(` is a special character. But I get the same error.

Comment: The error probably comes from the original `echo` command, since the problematic line is still there after you append the corrected line to `bash_profile`. You should edit your `bash_profile` instead, and correct the line by escaping the parenthesis using the editor.

Comment: @k314159 I just tested the command and echo is fine with it. Dot-sourcing the file causes the error that OP describes though.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the value containing special characters in single quotes:

```
echo "export ABC='Abcd123456%('" >> testing.txt
```

Then export should be alright with it:

```
user@host:~$ . testing.txt
user@host:~$ env | grep ABC
ABC=Abcd123456%(
user@host:~$
```